# Passing in an Image.Source to a XAML style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement a button style that has both an image and a caption that are specified when the style is used.

Here is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FF9E9FA3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>             
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I am using it like this:

```
<Button Tag="edit.png" Content="Edit" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<Button Tag="save.png" Content="Save" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Content works as expected and two buttons show up with the correct words in the label, but the images do not show up. If I use the ControlTemplate directly in  (no style) and replace {TemplateBinding} with the image file name, the images do appear.

Obviously I am using the Tag wrong or the Image wrong.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you replace

```
<Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" />
```

by

```
<Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

because then the necessary type conversion from string to ImageSource is performed automatically.